# init react-redux-form with values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I have a react-redux-form which I try to init with model values from store state.

The `form` looks like this (i removed everything but the first control for brevity):

```
<Form model="form.swimToEdit" onSubmit={(s) => props.handleSubmit(s)}>
                
                    <Control model="swimToEdit.competition" component={customTextField} 
                      

      ... removed for brevity ....
                
        </Form>
```

The `customTextField` :

```
const customTextField = (props) => {
        return (
            <TextField
                hintText={props.hintText}
                floatingLabelText= {props.floatingLabelText}
                {...props}
            />
        );
    }
```

Using the react tools on Chrome, i can see the modelValue is correctly populated in the Form:

[see the chrome tools screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IIacKqP1ZaNs_snXc9tWedyyXxYUNUYs/view?usp=sharing)

So i think the reducer is ok.

But the model value does not reach the control (text field) and the field turns out empty. What am i missing?

There are no examples in the [official guide](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/recipes/quickstart.html) so any examples, help is much appreciated.